# Avoid needing empty constructor for header node of collection

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, nodes, default-constructor

I have a collection I'm writing which is a form of linked list, but it has a header node.  Each node stores an object of template type T.  If I didn't need to initialize the header node, then I would not need to require that T has an empty constructor.  Furthermore, I never have any reason to look at the object in the header node.  Is there some way to leave the memory reserved for that object un-initialized?  Then I don't need to require clients to implement an empty constructor.

Comment: Please show some code, would be helpful.

Comment: There are two ways to do this. 1) Have the head be a different class than the children. 2) allocate the values to the heap (nullable type). I like 1 better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `union` in your nodes and construct the value within only when it is used. Using this approach is sort of midway between allocating the content separately and using a different type for the head node: it would still occopy memory for the unused content but it neither requires an extra allocation/indirection nor a default constructor for the content.

Comment: I think I like this answer best, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the destructor in this case.  Unfortunately the header node doesn't know it's a header node.  Is there some way to pass an argument to the destructor to tell it whether to call T's destructor or not?  Can I explicitly call T's destructor?

Comment: @dspyz: there isn't any way to pass a different parameter than the object under destruction to the destructor. You'll need to be able to determine from the object's state what kind of object is stored in the `union`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are aware of `std::list` and `std::forward_list`. If so and you still want to write you're own linked list to get the behaviour you want your best bet is to use `std::aligned_storage` in conjunction with placement `new`.

Or if you have access to boost, you can just delete that responsibility to `boot::optional`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Specifically, I'm writing a forward_list where elements can be erased rather than erase_after'd (because the iterator internally stays one step behind where it points to), and iterators aren't invalidated when their element gets erased.  They're effectively moved to the next valid element (each node keeps a ptr_count like a shared_ptr and only is deleted from memory when that count goes to zero.  When an element is erased, it's pointer turns to point to the previous element so any iterator sitting on it can follow the chain back to the next valid element)

Comment: @dspyz wouldn't it make more sense to just write a proxy iterator and possibly some helper free functions? ie  `erase(my_list, my_proxy_iter);`??

Comment: I'm having serious memory issues.  Building this on top of existing STL structures will inevitably require extra pointers/memory.  ie if I just keep a forward_list of shared_ptrs, then I need the extra memory for the pointers to the counts, whereas this way it can simply be part of the node object